# PostgreSQL - copy CSV file WHERE file EXIST

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this request :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 (col1 text, col2 text);
COPY table1 FROM '/path/to/csv/Tab.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I want that if the file `Tab.csv` exist it will run the request `COPY` but if it does not exist it will go to the next request without displaying the error.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: In what environment are you executing these commands?  Does that environment have features to test for a file's existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before the statement, try telling postgres to ignore errors

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE
```

and then when you're done, remember to set it back ;)